# Distributed tracing with Elastic APM on .NET Core, non-HTTP

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, distributed-tracing, elastic-apm

I am interested in using Elastic APM within an ASP.NET Core to instrument traces of a set of services which communicate over a mix of protocols (HTTP, SQS, SNS). Despite reviewing the documentation, I am not clear how I can use the [Elastic APM Public API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html) to connect transactions to one another which occur outside of HTTP (HttpClient is automatically instrumented for trace by Elastic APM).

According to the documentation, I should be able to serialize the `CurrentTransaction.OutgoingDistributedTracingData` on the caller and then deserialize it to resume the transaction on the callee, but despite implementing this pattern in memory, my traces in Kibana are missing spans from all but the final transaction.

```
// transaction 1
var trans1 = Agent.Tracer.StartTransaction("Dist Trans 2", ApiConstants.TypeRequest);

await trans1.CaptureSpan("step 1 processing", ApiConstants.ActionExec, async () => await Task.Delay(30));

// transaction 2
var trans2 = Agent.Tracer.StartTransaction("Dist Trans 2", ApiConstants.TypeRequest,
    DistributedTracingData.TryDeserializeFromString(trans1.OutgoingDistributedTracingData.SerializeToString()));

await trans2.CaptureSpan("step 2 processing", ApiConstants.ActionExec, async () => await Task.Delay(30));

// transaction 3
var trans3 = Agent.Tracer.StartTransaction("Dist Trans 2", ApiConstants.TypeRequest,
    DistributedTracingData.TryDeserializeFromString(trans2.OutgoingDistributedTracingData.SerializeToString()));

await trans3.CaptureSpan("step 3 processing", ApiConstants.ActionExec, async () => await Task.Delay(30));

trans3.End();
```

[image: kibana trace dashboard]

My implementation spike can be found on [Github](https://github.com/lakario/elastic-apm-test/blob/master/TestElasticApm/Startup.cs#L56-L95).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't end `trans1` and `trans2`.

Just put these 2 lines to the point where these end, and everything should show up fine:

```
trans1.End();
trans2.End();
```

There is the [`CaptureTransaction`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html#convenient-capture-transaction), which is a convenient method that can wrap you any code and makes sure the transaction is ended and all exceptions are captured - so you use that method and it does "everything" for you.

Then there is the [`StartTransaction`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html#api-start-transaction) method - this is the one you use in your code -, which starts the transaction and does not do anything else. The advantage here is that you get an `ITransaction` instance which you can use wherever and whenever you want. But in this case you need to call `.End()` on it manually once the transaction (aka the code you want to capture) is executed.

Same with [`CaptureSpan`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html#convenient-capture-span) and [`StartSpan`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html#api-transaction-create-span).

So you used `CaptureSpan` for your spans, so those where ended automatically when the lambda with `Task.Delay` finished, on the other hand you started your transactions with `StartTransaction` but only called `.End()` on `trans3` and not on the 2 other transactions.

There is some explanation with a demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGqu59DN14&feature=youtu.be&t=3413) - sample code of that demo is [here](https://github.com/gregkalapos/MicrosoftDevUserGroupGraz_StateOfObservability_Talk/blob/master/Samples/06_DtOverCmd/Program.cs).

Comment: I experimented with this originally. It was counter intuitive to me to "end" the transaction which I was trying to extend or continue. When I did it the first time, I must have screwed it up because traces were not being connected. That said, trying it again now, and my traces are working for both my examples in the linked repo. Awesome.

Comment: That's a good point: so it's better to think about this in a way that you don't really extend or continue the transaction. The terminology Elastic APM uses are: Trace, Transaction, Span. The 3 transactions here are normal transactions that you end normally, but they together form a trace - so you don't "continue" the transactions, you just make sure they are part of the same trace. Some hopefully helpful docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/distributed-tracing.html